# Is there a way to know what all migrations have been applied to Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Is there a way to know what all migrations have been applied to Rails database?

I am looking for a command-line option, rather than checking the `schema_migrations` table in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rake db:version` will give you the current "schema version number" which should match the filename of the last migration that was executed.

Answer (score 1):

To check the status of specific migrations, you can use the following Rake task:

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

This will output a table with the status of `up` or `down` for each migration:

```sh
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     migration_id    migration_name
```

In your case, you can check if you have any migration not applied:

```
rails db:migrate:status | grep down
```